# Operator's Efficiency

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

Good day, I have assigned a task where I have to calculate efficiency per operator as shown in image below. But I have no idea how to get the correct formula. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

[image: Operator Efficiency]

Answer (score 0):

You could take the shift duration multiplied by the pieces per minute to get a maximum possible then compare with actual produced ie

Efficiency is output / input...

But the downtime may need to be included,

Is downtime acceptable?

If so - how much?

Then perhaps account for minimum allowed downtime by reducing the time for the maximum calculation ie (shift hours - downtime) * pieces per min...